# Changes to manifest file do not apply when testing Outlook Web Add-in (C#) project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, outlook-web-addins

I've created a Outlook Web Add-in (C#) project in Visual Studio Enterprise 2022  (Version 17.6.0 Preview 2.0)

To be able to log into my E-mail account I had to select the properties of the manifest project and change "Use Multi-factor auth" to True.

Now pressing Start in Visual Studio it opens Google Chrome, and automatically goes to Outlook. I log in with my E-mail account. When I select a message in my inbox I can see all the normal functions in the title bar, like reply, and reply-all.
If I press the square button, with 4 squares inside, a dropdown opens containing a button with the same name as my project.
Clicking the button executes the expected behaviour of the default project: A task pane opens showing info about the selected message.

The problem arises when I close the browser, stop running in visual studio, and then make changes to the manifest file.
I change the following lines:

```
<DisplayName DefaultValue="OutlookWebAddIn" />
<Description DefaultValue="OutlookWebAddIn"/>
```

to

```
<DisplayName DefaultValue="Test" />
<Description DefaultValue="Test"/>
```

Running the app again, and going through the same steps, the button in the dropdown appears with the name unchanged.

It feels like the manifest file is cached somewhere, but I have no clue how to fix that.

**Troubleshoot steps I've tried:**

- I've tried making other changes to the manifest file, with no changes being applied as I run the app.
- Running in Edge browser instead
- Clearing all browser cache up to 7 days ago
- Creating a new project (this did not work at all, still showed the first add-in when running, only when pressing the add-in button the code was unable to run)
- Closing and opening visual studio
- Somehow the name changes did end up applying when I opened the project the next day. Making new changes did not have any effect.

**To reproduce:**

- Create a new Outlook Web Add-in (C#) project in Visual Studio and run it
- Verify that the add-in exists by selecting a message and finding the add-in button on that message.
- Stop running and make changes to the manifest file
- Run it again and see that the changes are not applied

Comment: Can you try clearing cache as mentioned here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache

Comment: Yes, I have tried to "Manually clear the cache in Outlook" by going to Get Add-ins > My Add-ins > Custom Add-ins and removing the Add-in.

Here, it shows with the correctly updated name.

When stopping and starting Visual Studio again, the Add-in is back to its old state, with the incorrect name.

Comment: We are currently seeing a delay of up to four hours for manifest installation/updation to reflect. If you are still facing the issue and delay is more than four hours please do let us know